# Why text baseline height different when use Tailwind CSS?

Tags: tailwind-css, font-style, line-height

```html
<button type="button" class="flex items-center px-5 py-2 bg-[#152DB5] rounded-[9.9rem]">
  <svg><!-- ... --></svg>
  <span class="inline-block align-middle text-[1.4rem] font-[700] leading-[2.2rem] tracking-[-0.01em] text-[#fff]">코드 올리기</span>
</button>
```

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWA8F.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc04m.png)

Hello!

I use Tailwind CSS. Image2 is button that use tailwind CSS. Image1 is button that pure CSS.

Why text baseline height different when use Tailwind CSS?

two span use same font style is

```css
font-size: 1.4rem;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 20px;
letter-spacing: -0.01em;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind CSS defines a default `line-height` for each font-size utility. You can view the default values in the [Font Size Documentation Page](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size) under properties.

You can also provide a default `font-size`, `line-height`, `letter-spacing`, `font-weight` and disable the default values by changing them in your `tailwind.config.js` file: [link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size#providing-a-default-line-height).

> Tailwind’s default theme configures a sensible default line-height for each text-{size} utility. You can configure your own default line heights when using custom font sizes by defining each size using a tuple of the form [fontSize, lineHeight] in your tailwind.config.js file.